# Can't find SQL query syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I have a query that involves three tables. Here it is:

```
SELECT
   u.email,
   (o.rec_amount+o.delivery_price-o.cheques_amount-o.discount_amount-o.money_amount),
   COUNT( i.id )      
FROM
   orders AS o      
LEFT JOIN
   orders_items AS i 
      ON o.id = i.order_id      
WHERE
   o.status_id =5 
   AND (
      o.rec_amount+o.delivery_price-o.cheques_amount-o.discount_amount-o.money_amount
   ) > 0      
GROUP BY
   user_id      
HAVING
   COUNT( i.id ) > 0      
LEFT JOIN
   users AS u 
      ON o.user_id = u.id      
ORDER BY
   (o.rec_amount+o.delivery_price-o.cheques_amount-o.discount_amount-o.money_amount) DESC
```

> Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'LEFT JOIN users AS u ON o.user_id = u.id ORDER BY
>   (o.rec_amount+o.delivery_price' at line 7

If I remove the second `LEFT JOIN` and of course the u.email from select that is a column from that joined table it works:

```
SELECT
   (o.rec_amount+o.delivery_price-o.cheques_amount-o.discount_amount-o.money_amount),
   COUNT( i.id )      
FROM
   orders AS o      
LEFT JOIN
   orders_items AS i 
      ON o.id = i.order_id      
WHERE
   o.status_id =5 
   AND (
      o.rec_amount+o.delivery_price-o.cheques_amount-o.discount_amount-o.money_amount
   ) > 0      
GROUP BY
   user_id      
HAVING
   COUNT( i.id ) > 0      
ORDER BY
   (o.rec_amount+o.delivery_price-o.cheques_amount-o.discount_amount-o.money_amount) DESC
```

Thanks for help.

Edit: Thanks guys, this worked:

```
SELECT
   u.email,
   (o.rec_amount+o.delivery_price-o.cheques_amount-o.discount_amount-o.money_amount),
   COUNT( i.id )      
FROM
   orders AS o      
LEFT JOIN
   orders_items AS i 
      ON o.id = i.order_id      
LEFT JOIN
   users AS u 
      ON o.user_id = u.id      
WHERE
   o.status_id =5 
   AND (
      o.rec_amount+o.delivery_price-o.cheques_amount-o.discount_amount-o.money_amount
   ) > 0      
GROUP BY
   u.email      
HAVING
   COUNT( i.id ) > 0      
ORDER BY
   (o.rec_amount+o.delivery_price-o.cheques_amount-o.discount_amount-o.money_amount) DESC
```

Comment: GROUP BY/HAVING should be after all joins.

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING and WHERE sections have to be after all JOIN sections.